# Unable to run Playwright with cucumber due to errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, cucumberjs, playwright-test

Apologies if the errors are pretty simple. I'm trying my hand at a Playwright TS repo with cucumber js. I've worked with Playwright and Cucumber before, with JS, but not TS. So, it's my first foray with TS.

I'm trying to implement the POM that I've worked in the past with my other Playwright/Cucumber projects. However I've been hit with multiple errors - have tried a lot of hit and trial methods but each one turning into a dead end.

Error -

```
@Smoke
  Scenario: User is able to login with valid credentials # features/login.feature:3
    Given User is on the "Login" Page
User is on the Login Page
    ✖ failed
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit_base_url' of undefined
          at /Users/Rahul_Yadav/Documents/FE-Projects/play-cuke-ts/src/step-definitions/login.step.ts:16:24
          at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
          at fulfilled (/Users/Rahul_Yadav/Documents/FE-Projects/play-cuke-ts/src/step-definitions/login.step.ts:5:58)
          at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
          at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
```

Here is the repo for issue reproduction purposes - https://github.com/zac11/play-cuke-ts

Can someone please help me in this issue? If there are issues with configuration, the please also mention what updates I should do.

Comment: Did you try with put the const loginmethods = new loginMethods(); inside the Given(test) scope?

Comment: Wouldn't that make it available only in that block?

Comment: yes but if you arent using any state in the methods i think it may be worth a try to instantiate it there (if i remember correctly cypress does some weird source code splitting where parts are executed in a different context and dont have access to the same scope )

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to say, in the context of the question? Sorry but I'm not able to translate your comments

Comment: Are you sure the way you are instantiating "page" is correct? " global.page = await global.context.newPage();"

Comment: Please check it , as I have gone through your repo , I find this line a possible culprit in terms of scope of "page" variable.

Comment: If I want the page declaration to be done at first, at global level, shouldn't this be done in the way? If not, how can I define the browser to open at beforeall hook?